How to create a LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid that items aligned to start for every even index?
I need to have a LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid that aligns every even item to the left no matter of other which height other items have but while aligning depends height of last 2 items it aligns item to the right as

with
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
    verticalItemSpacing = 8.dp,
//            horizontalArrangement = arrangement
) {
    items(3) {
        val height = if (it == 0) {
            240.dp
        } else 150.dp

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(itemWidth, height)
                .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text("Item: $it", fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}

I also tried using a custom arrangement with
val arrangement = remember {
    object : Arrangement.Horizontal {

        var size = 0
        override fun Density.arrange(
            totalSize: Int,
            sizes: IntArray,
            layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
            outPositions: IntArray,
        ) {

            println(
                "total size: $totalSize," +
                        " sizes: ${sizes.size}, " +
                        "outPositions: ${outPositions.size}"
            )
//                        sizes.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
//                            size = if (index % 2 == 0) 0 else i
//                            try {
//                                outPositions[i] = size
//                            } catch (e: Exception) {
//                                e.printStackTrace()
//                            }
//                        }

        }

    }
}

But it returns 2 items while there are 3 items.
Tried same thing with FlowRow which works as i needed when only there are 3 items

FlowRow(
    maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {

    repeat(3){
        val height = if (it == 0) {
            240.dp
        } else 150.dp

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(itemWidth, height)
                .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text("Item: $it", fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}

but when item count is bigger it doesn't work as staggered grid should work obviously being a Row with 2 items and not aligning in staggered grid manner.

How to make custom arrangement or something else with LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid so it aligns items starting from left no matter what height other items have?
Full code to play around or reproduce the issue
@Preview
@Composable
fun StaggeredGridAlignTest() {

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        val itemWidth = maxWidth / 2 - 8.dp

        val arrangement = remember {
            object : Arrangement.Horizontal {

                var size = 0
                override fun Density.arrange(
                    totalSize: Int,
                    sizes: IntArray,
                    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
                    outPositions: IntArray,
                ) {

                    println(
                        "total size: $totalSize," +
                                " sizes: ${sizes.size}, " +
                                "outPositions: ${outPositions.size}"
                    )
//                        sizes.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
//                            size = if (index % 2 == 0) 0 else i
//                            try {
//                                outPositions[i] = size
//                            } catch (e: Exception) {
//                                e.printStackTrace()
//                            }
//                        }

                }

            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

            LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
                columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
                verticalItemSpacing = 8.dp,
                horizontalArrangement = arrangement
            ) {
                items(3) {
                    val height = if (it == 0) {
                        240.dp
                    } else 150.dp

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(itemWidth, height)
                            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Text("Item: $it", fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
                    }
                }
            }

            FlowRow(
                maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {

                repeat(3) {
                    val height = if (it == 0) {
                        240.dp
                    } else 150.dp

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(itemWidth, height)
                            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Text("Item: $it", fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm not sure if this requirement makes sense on a conceptual level. It might defeat the whole purpose of a lazy layout depending how the lazy loading in Compose is implemented. Say that the left items always have 100.dp height, and the right items have 50.dp height. Now, let's add 1001 items to our LazyVerticalGrid. If you scroll to the 250th row, you will have item with index 500 on the left and item with index 1001 to the right. So there is a linearly growing distance of item indices being displayed at the same time. Would Compose correctly lazy load the needed items?

Items are not guaranteed to have same height though and in general it should act as staggered grid not depending on any height of any item. I tried adding another item at the end if number of items is odd. And it creates extra space below the ui and still aligns to right in some cases depending on difference of height. Dimensions of Composables are not known beforehand, it's a list of images that displayed 2 on each Column with height determined by aspect ratio of images. It's not guaranteed to add which height should be added to work.

I'm not interested much about laziness though. I also checked its horizontalArrangment param is not wokring for which is noted with arrangement specifying horizontal spacing between items. The item arrangement specifics are ignored for now.. That must be the reason it doesn't return correct params in onArrange i guess. I think i will write a custom Layout when i'm available
